# Where to store user login information?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, security

I am trying to make an ASP.NET MVC 3 app in which I have my own authentication system. I have followed some bits written on [this site](http://bradygaster.com/custom-authentication-with-mvc-3.0) which I found in another SO post.

About half-way down the page the author writes a short session manager to persist user login information. I obviously want to do this as well, but the author hints that this is not a good way of doing things and that there are other, better, ways of doing this.

That's all well and good, but what are those better ways of going about persisting log in information?

For now I persist user name, user ID and log in status to the session, because I need to pull out user-specific info every so often and the user name is handy to have quick access to rather than having to re-query the database on every page.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I wish I could mark more than 1 as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends about your needs.

Session:

- saved on server so consume server resources
- most secure (no one can modify session data)
- lost when user close browser

Cookie:

- saved on client browser (doesn't consume server resources)
- is less secure because it's accessible on the client pc and on the network (so is a good idea to encrypt cookies, specially login informations cookies)
- you can persist it through different session

Generally speaking when you have a problem like "rather than having to requery the database on every page" ask yourself if you can use [ASP.Net Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I use FormsAuthentication and create a ticket with user serialized data attached to it.  This is pretty much a cookie, but is supported well within the .NET environment.

Since you mentioned a "roll-your-own" solution, this is what I use in these situations.

This creates a FormsAuthentication ticket:

```
var authTicket = new System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now + System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Timeout, false, this.Serialize(someObject));

var encrypt = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

var authCookie = new HttpCookie(System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypt) { HttpOnly = true };
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
```

This grabs the ticket information:

```
var result = new FormsAuthenticationTicketData((HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity).Ticket.UserData);
```

There are several ways to Serialize your data into the cookie, but I serialize it into JSON before putting it in the cookie (the object must be able to be serialized):

```
public string Serialize(object someObject)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var output = serializer.Serialize(someObject);

    return output;
}
```

To use the data, all you have to do is deserialize it.  Remember, all you really want to pass around with this ticket is some identify data that can be used to pull "private" information from your controllers or your AuthorizeAttribute overrides.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I use session as well for my applications and it works almost fine in all scenarios, So ill prefer session over cookies or cache